# vs code asking for authorization code in changing Firebase account during installation

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

```
? Which Firebase account would you like to use? 
> [Login in with another account]
> ********* (other Firebase account logged in)

? Which Firebase account would you like to use? [Login in with another account]
? Enter authorization code:
```

Where do I get the authorization code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! you should first run

```
firebase login
```

then

```
firebase init
```

before running

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

It is a step-by-step process.